# SQL. Select category descendants

Tags: mysql, terms, hierarchical

How does Wordpress fetches subcategories for a given category? I tried to figure it out from the code, but I have not succeeded.
My real question is: is it possible to make some recursive sql query that will select all the term descendants. Or the recursion must be on PHP level?

Comment: What are you trying to do that this solves? It's difficult to answer this appropriatley without the context. Are you trying to create a side menu for terms?

Comment: @TomJNowell No, I rewrite a WP site to NodeJS and (at least at this step) I continue to use original Wordpress database. So I have write some replacements to Wordpress functions. For example, to get all post from certain category.

Comment: Now I see that WP fetches all category tree from DB and process it on PHP level.

Comment: That's a pretty massive piece of info you ommitted. Most people usually use Node for a frontend then make REST API calls to an existing WP interface, they don't interact with the WP database tables directly. Same goes for a lot of headless/decoupled frontends that talk to the REST API. It's a lot easier than re-implementing half of WP to get access to its data structures